# How to fetch specific attribute value from DynamoDB getItem in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am using Dynamodb Item - `getItem` API to get records from DynamoDB table. But it returns `Item` object and I want to retrieve specific attribute value from the `Item` object. How can we do it in Java? I couldn't find references.

```
Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);
Item item = table.getItem(hashKeyFieldName, hashKeyFieldValue);
```

The item contains the following fields:
`HashKey,  TimeStamp, NumRetries`

I want to get the specific NumRetries value from `item` above. Is it something that is possible? something like `int numRetries = item.get("NumRetries");`?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with a [Projection Expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html#DDB-GetItem-request-ProjectionExpression):

```
GetItemSpec spec = new GetItemSpec().withPrimaryKey("primaryKey", primaryKey)
             .withProjectionExpression("HashKey,  TimeStamp, NumRetries");
Item outcome = table.getItem(spec);
```

A [names map](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html#DDB-GetItem-request-ExpressionAttributeNames) may be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Projection Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ProjectionExpressions.html) to get certain attributes from an item but do keep in mind that **using projection expressions does not reduce the usage and cost of RCUs that are used in retrieving the object**.

Code example,

```
GetItemSpec spec = new GetItemSpec()
    .withPrimaryKey("YourPrimaryKey", value)
    .withProjectionExpression("NumRetries");

Item item = table.getItem(spec);

System.out.println(item.toJSONPretty());
```

More code examples can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPIItemCRUD.html#JavaDocumentAPIGetItem).